# Alfresco + Opsoro Setup

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco

I want to set up a content mgmt system. And i feel the combination of Alfresco with Opsoro is a gud one. Any other suggestions?

visit [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com) &
      [Opsoro](http://www.fme.de/Screencams/opsoro/opsoro.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer - I work for Alfresco.  Just wanted to point out - I recently created [a wiki page](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Category:Alternate_UIs) that tracks the different UIs available for Alfresco - Opsoro included.